# How to convert my native SQL query into a JPQL query

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm trying to convert a native SQL query into a JPQL query. Presented first are the JPA entities and the repository interface:

> **LearnerActivity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "learner_activity")
public class LearnerActivity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "learner_activity_unit",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="learner_activitys_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="units_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<Unit> units = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "learner_activity_performance_criteria",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="learner_activitys_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="performance_criterias_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<PerformanceCriteria> performanceCriterias = new HashSet<>();
}
```

> **LearnerJobOnSiteChecklistSectionItem**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "learner_job_on_site_checklist_section_item")
public class LearnerJobOnSiteChecklistSectionItem implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "learner_activity_id")
    private LearnerActivity learnerActivity;
}
```

> **LearnerPortfolioPerformanceCriteriaAchievement**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "learner_portfolio_performance_criteria_achievement")
public class LearnerPortfolioPerformanceCriteriaAchievement implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "performance_criteria_id")
    private PerformanceCriteria performanceCriteria;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "learner_portfolio_performance_criteria_achievement_learner_job_on_site_checklist_section_item",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="learner_portfolio_performance_criteria_achievements_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="learner_job_on_site_checklist_section_items_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<LearnerJobOnSiteChecklistSectionItem> learnerJobOnSiteChecklistSectionItems = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I'm looking to get all `LearnerPortfolioPerformanceCriteriaAchievement`s which have the same `PerformanceCriteria` as a given `LearnerJobOnSiteChecklistSectionItem`'s `Activity`.

> **LearnerPortfolioPerformanceCriteriaAchievementRepository**

```
public interface LearnerPortfolioPerformanceCriteriaAchievementRepository extends JpaRepository<LearnerPortfolioPerformanceCriteriaAchievement,Long> {
    @Query("select distinct lppca from LearnerJobOnSiteChecklistSectionItem si inner join si.learnerActivity la inner join LearnerPortfolioPerformanceCriteriaAchievement lppca where lppca.performanceCriteria member of la.performanceCriterias and si.id =:sectionItemId")
    public List<LearnerPortfolioPerformanceCriteriaAchievement> findForSectionItem(@Param("sectionItemId") Long sectionItemId);
}
```

> **Native SQL**

```
SELECT
  a.id
FROM
  learner_job_on_site_checklist_section_item AS i
JOIN
  learner_activity_performance_criteria AS c
ON
  c.learned_activitys_id = i.learned_activitys_id
INNER JOIN
  learner_portfolio_performance_criteria_achievement AS a
ON
  a.performance_criteria_id = c.performance_criterias_id
where i.id = 2
```

Understanding that I can replace my SQL `ON` with `WHERE` clauses, my best JPQL attempt so far is this:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT lppca
FROM
  LearnerJobOnSiteChecklistSectionItem si
INNER JOIN
  si.learnerActivity la
INNER JOIN
  LearnerPortfolioPerformanceCriteriaAchievement lppca
WHERE
  lppca.performanceCriteria MEMBER OF la.performanceCriterias
AND si.id =:sectionItemId
```

However, running this JPQL throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'lppca' {originalText=lppca}
```

Comment: When posting a question keep the code to the minimum possible for readers to read easily. Right now it is too cumbersome due to the length of the code and scaringly long class names. I have removed some code that has no bearing on the problem description or the answer so that the question is easier to read.

Comment: Appreciate the time you've spent. Comments noted for future questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will work:

```
SELECT
  a
FROM
  LearnerPortfolioPerformanceCriteriaAchievement  a
  , LearnerActivity                               v
  , LearnerJobOnSiteChecklistSectionItem          i
WHERE
  i.id                                            = :sectionItemId
AND i.learnerActivity                             = v
AND a.performanceCriteria                         MEMBER OF v.performanceCriterias
AND i                                             MEMBER OF a.learnerJobOnSiteChecklistSectionItems
```

Have created a [sample application](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/37565902) to test the query (I have used shorter and simpler class names to make it easy to read).